# Textarea name change without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textarea

well, i have TEXTAREA in a form.

```
<textarea name="content_en"></textarea>
```

and also i have three buttons near this textarea:

```
<button class="button_en>EN</button>
<button class="button_ro>RO</button>
<button class="button_ru>RU</button>
```

i want to do this:
to change textarea name when i press a button without page refreshing or something like that.
so this is to put different content in different columns from a row from database. (Content in different languages under same ID)

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Change the class of the buttons and move atual class to other param like 'data-txt':

```
<button class="button-change-txt" data-txt="en">EN</button>
<button class="button-change-txt" data-txt="ro">RO</button>
<button class="button-change-txt" data-txt="ru">RU</button>
```

Then, add a class to textarea:

```
<textarea class="txt-content" name="content_en"></textarea>
```

So, add an event to ".button-change-txt" class:

```
$('.button-change-txt').click(function(){
    var txt = $(this).attr('data-txt'); //STORE THE data-txt INTO A VARIABLE
    $('.txt-content').attr('name','content_'+txt); //CHANGE THE TEXTAREA NAME
})
```

Comment: thanks...but something is not working and for some reasons that i saw in my code...i think that i should have three divs and three textarea. Those three divs like buttons.
Are shown three buttons and one textarea1.
when i press on button2 it should change taxtarea1 with textarea2. and when i press button3 it should appear textarea3. hope u understood me and i hope you'll help me. thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Some would recommend using the "on" method instead of the "click" method, seeing as the .click() method simply points to .on('click'), thus:

```
$('.button-change-txt').on('click', function(){
    var txt = $(this).attr('data-txt');
    $('.txt-content').attr(name,'content_'+txt);
});
```